# Remove "empty" bytes from buffer in Node.js

Tags: node.js, buffer

I have this code:

```
  const start = pos * 100;
  const b = Buffer.alloc(99);
  fs.readSync(logFD, b, 0, b.length, start);
  console.log(String(b)); 
  const j = JSON.parse(String(b).trim());
```

I am getting this error:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token  in JSON at position 15

The problem is likely that I have empty bytes in my buffer:

```
7b22 7022 3a37 3236 3736 2c22 6222 3a31
3837 7d00 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
```

I don't know how many bytes to read, so I have to read more than a threshold and then trim it down..is there some way I can remove the empty bytes from the buffer before converting to a string?

Answer (score 5):

So I think this works:

```
  const i = b.indexOf(0x00);
  const nb = b.slice(0, i);
```

I just remove after the first index of the hex 0x00 showing up